# Package for Debian 7 on Debian 8

Tags: debian, couchbase

I want to install Couchbase server on Debian 8.0 but the released packages are only for Debian 7.

Generally: What problems could arise from installing package for older distro version? Any drawbacks?

Does anybody have experience specifically with Couchbase server?

I am quite new to linux administration so it would be great if you could be a little verbose :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should not have any particular issues. Debian is really stable regarding location of files. (/etc/ /var/log/ /var/lib etc...).

The only problem that could arise is if they decide to change the "system" (init/upstart/systemd) process between 7 and 8 but even with this it should be backward compatible.

System process if the one have PID 0 which is the first process start at boot. It is in charge of starting all other processes/daemon.

Old one is **init** but some year ago, it was decided to replace it with newer version solving important issues. There was two main concurrents **upstart** and **systemd** (red hat likes). At first debian/ubuntu goes for upstart which was pushed by Canonical (ubuntu) but after a comminity vote between two, it was decided to use **systemd** so last ubuntu/debian (should) use **systemd** (or upstart if not migrated yet).
Note both are still compatible with **init** script

Comment: And things like dependencies on libraries available only in 7 but not in 8? Is that possibly an issue?

Comment: That could be an issue but using package manager apt-get/aptitude should be able to manage dependencies issues.
Do you plan to use **dpkg** to install it ?

Comment: Yes, the package is **.deb**.